# Expand List jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some questions:

A) How can I switch between '+' and '-' when the list is expand (+) or not expand (-), and the correct expand symbol when I load my page.

B) How can I have the correct checkbox value on my principal lists when I load my page. For the first list '-', the second Checked box symbol, and the third no checked).

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zE4CA/)

```
 <ul class="list">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
   ....
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: zak zak - check out this jsfiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/Y3qN5/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
//Expand list. 
$('.list > li b').click(function() {
    var span = $(this).find('span');
    var text = span.text();
    span.text(text === "+"?"-":"+")
    $(this).parent().find('ul').toggle();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zE4CA/1/)

Comment: And for the question B, my checkbox list has any check symbol :(

Comment: @zakzak can you explain a bit more.? i could not get you..!